# Identification of Audible Sound Waveform Equation

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency

I am working on an assignment for a Computational Optimisation module.

The problem requires a method of guessing each dimension of a six-dimensional vector.

The six dimensional vector has the form:

$$\textbf{X} = \{\alpha_1, \omega_1, \alpha_2, \omega_2, \alpha_3, \omega_3\}$$

The equation these parameters go into has the form:

$$y(t) = \alpha_1 \sin(\omega_1 t \theta +\alpha_2 \sin(\omega_2 t \theta +\alpha_3 \sin(\omega_3 t \theta))){\textrm{ }}(1)$$

So the exercise would work something like the following:

I get given this equation, with the six parameters already set, and I have to write an algorithm to recover them:

$$y_0(t) = 1 \sin(5 t \theta) -(1.5 \sin(4.8 t \theta +2 \sin(4.9 t \theta)))$$

$\theta$ has been defined as:

$$\theta = \frac{2 \pi}{100}$$

All of the parameters of $\textbf{X}$ have been restricted to a closed interval such that:

$$\{X_i \in \mathbb{R} | -6.4 \leq x \leq 6.35\}$$

I can evaluate the `fitness' of my guess using the following function, which just gets me the square difference between the function using my guessed parameters, and the function using the original parameters.

$$f(\textbf{X}) = \sum_{t=0}^{100}\left(y(t) -y_0(t)\right)^2$$

I would like to understand more about how the equation describing the sound's waveform works (equation 1) so that I can write a little on the physics background in my assignment. I know it has something to do with frequency modulation, and have a notional qualitative understanding of what frequency modulation is, and that it is being applied, in this case, to audible sound waves.

I would be looking for information on how it is derived, and why it has the form, and number of parameters that it does.
I don't know what the equation is called, so I am struggling to find anything on Google.

Is anybody able to suggest some resources which might be useful or a few keywords I could search for?

Appreciate any help,
Thanks

Comment: "the equation describing the sound's waveform" would be the wave equation--Google it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see an equation of the form I have described. Wolfram describes 'the wave equation' as follows: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WaveEquation.html

Comment: @user45664 Just to clarify, I am not asking 'what is the equation to describe a wave'. I am asking, 'can anybody help identify the equation above - I think it has something to do with audible sound waves and frequency modulation'. Thanks

Comment: Clarify your question i.e.: MY QUESTION IS (one or two sentences with an equation number for the specific equation)

Comment: @user45664 - Thanks for your help again, I have added a number by the equation in question. Hopefully, that clarifies things a little. Let me know if you recognise it. Thanks!

Comment: @user45664 I also found this last night: http://web.mysites.ntu.edu.sg/epnsugan/PublicSite/Shared%20Documents/CEC%202011-%20RWP/Tech-Rep.pdf which presumably inspired the question in class (see page 3). Didn't help me identify the equation though.